# How can I add a time delay to my divs, so they appear one after the other like a powerpoint slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So say I want div 1 to appear after 2 seconds, div 2 to appear after 7 seconds, and div 3 to appear after 15 seconds.

Is there a way for me to add an inline style element that will make the divs go from hidden but occupying space to fully visible.

I've been searching and most things I've found are hover/click triggered. I can't seem to find anything with a time trigger.

Thank you.

Edit: To make this more clear, I am looking for any kind of code that has a time delay to appear. When I search transition, I get a bunch of code based on actions, like a click or a hover. I am not looking for a user action to trigger this, just a time.

When I search for animation, I get a bunch of results about moving images, which I also do not need.

When I search for time delay, I get a bunch of results about time delay transitions, which is how long after the user action occurs does the transition occur which still requires user input, and I do not want user input.

I am more asking what I should be looking for, if there is a word for it or something you are familiar that does this. I didn't provide any code because I don't want you coding me something. I'm asking for lead, because it is frustrating that I cannot find the proper word to identify what I need.

Comment: take a look at .delay() here: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Perhaps you are searching for something like this: http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/

Comment: This is not a format to "wish" for code. Show the efford you allready have gone through your self and explain where you are stuck. When you have nothing, and no idea what to do, hire someone.

Comment: This link might help you to a solution: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/effects

Comment: FYI @RichardCane, Nico's comment wasn't hostile. He's just explaining that SO is not a coding service and that the barrier for posting here is set high so that 1) people don't rely on others to code something that they haven't already tried themselves and 2) we have an opportunity to help when all the information is available to us. Posting a weak question with no thought put into it is considered bad form.

Comment: OP, as others have posted the JS function you're looking for is `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I'm on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can either use a css transition to animate the visibility property after a set delay in your stylesheet, or you can change the visibility property using JS and setTimeout();

HTML

```
<div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility = "visible";
},1000);
```

This sets a callback to override the css property after 1000 ms, or 1 second.

For a pure css solution we can use this instead. We need to provide multiples of a few properties, for cross platform compatibility.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
.fade-in {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}
```

So this class called fade-in adds a 1s animation to any element it's added to, it will start as soon as it's loaded as it is. It's opacity based so the object will take up space when it's invisible, if you don't want this you need to use a variation on display:none.

A delay can be added to an element using

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2s;
animation-delay: 2s;
```

Just set that with a different value for each 'slide' to get them to fade in at different times.

Comment: A pur CSS would be excellent if its not too much trouble

Comment: Ok it's a little longer in terms of lines but shouldn't be too difficult to implement

Comment: There you go, can trim the -webkit/-moz property versions as required. Check out caniuse.com for support :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the space taken up - meaning you don't want things collapsed up, I would create the div, and set it's `display` to `none`, and then the `opacity` to `0`. This will hide the element, but it will still take up physical space on your page.

Then I would create a css class called "show" or something like that:

**CSS:**

```
.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Then with jQuery (or javascript) you could use either [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), or [setTimeOut](http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/). In your timeout function, you could dynamiclly assign the "show" class to each element. This would fade each element in after "x" seconds you specify.

Something like this:

**jQuery:**

```
 $(function() {
     setTimeout(function(){
         showElement();
      }, 3000);

     function showElement() {
         $('my-div').toggleClass('show');
     }
  });
```